# how to enable and configure USB OTG for device mode on iMX31 Litekit?

Tags: embedded, usb, arm, driver, usb-otg

I need to configure USB OTG on iMX31 for device mode. We need a raw channel between the host and target and usb seems to be the best suited. However I haven't been able to correctly configure the OTG controller. I dont know what I am missing. I have performed the steps mentioned in section 32.14.1 of iMX31 Reference Manual. I have also configured PORTSC1 register for ULPI.

Can any one help me out here? any poineters/code/any thing that can help me is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Didn't the kit come with sample code for that?

Comment: No. No source code and there are like 3000 pages of documentation :(

Answer (score 2):

The litekit is supported by the [vanilla Linux kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35/arch/arm/mach-mx3/mach-mx31lite.c).

It's pretty easy to declare the OTG for device mode. You just need to declare it as device when you register your device:

```
static struct fsl_usb2_platform_data usb_pdata = {
     .operating_mode = FSL_USB2_DR_DEVICE,
     .phy_mode       = FSL_USB2_PHY_ULPI,
};
```

Register code:

```
mxc_register_device(&mxc_otg_udc_device, &usb_pdata);
```

Don't forget to configure the pads for the physical ULPI lines, and eventually make the initial transactions for your transceiver.

You can find all the necessary code as I did it for the [moboard platform](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35/arch/arm/mach-mx3/mach-mx31moboard.c) and the [marxbot board](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35/arch/arm/mach-mx3/mx31moboard-marxbot.c) file.